# JavaScript String as Array: Read but no Write

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, language-design

For JavaScript in most browsers*, you can read a character from a String by treating it like an Array.  However, in all the browsers I've tried (IE9, Chrome, Firefox), you can't write to it like an Array.

[For example](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/tbN5K/):

```
var string = 'hello world';
alert(string[0]);//alerts 'h'
alert(string);//alerts 'hello world'

string[0]='j';
alert(string[0]);//alerts 'h'
alert(string);//alerts 'hello world'
```

This has repercussions for more than just JavaScript developers:

```
jelloPeople.roam();
```

**Does anybody know the reasoning behind this?**

For example, I've looked at [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#section_5), and they allude to it but don't give an explanation:

"..trying to set a character via indexing does not throw an error, but the string itself is unchanged."

Bottom Line:  It is strange and confusing to me that some array properties were given to Strings and not others.

**<strike>UPDATE:</strike>**

<strike>Ok, so JavaScript Strings are immutable objects, but why?  It seems like operations such as the above would be faster if they weren't immutable (change 1 character as opposed to making a new 11 character string).  In fact, I don't see a case with String functions where performance would be impacted negatively if they weren't immutable, but I see several where performance would be improved.  Also, there is no true multi-threading in JavaScript, so no advantage to immutables there.</strike>

(removed and will research this and possibly ask in a new quesion)

---

*Not IE 6 or 7

Comment: `jelloPeople.roam()`? What does that mean?

Comment: Read about [immutability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) -- good stuff to know.

Comment: @Vivn Paliath:  Sorry, it was a bad attempt at humor.

Comment: It's fairly common for strings to be immutable objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This simply because javascript strings are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) by design; once created they cannot be changed.

Answer (score 4):

I think it might be because strings in JavaScript are immutable. Notice that every string function doesn't actually change the string itself, but returns a new one. This is the same for changing characters directly, it wouldn't work with an immutable model.